# Objetos y clases Java

Tags: java

estuve aprendiendo muchos conceptos sobre java, pero hay algo que no para de darme vueltas.
¿Un objeto es una instancia?¿Por qué le dicen instancia?
También leí algo sobre un constructor o constructores, ¿Qué es?

Comment: Todo esto, esta respondido mil veces en google. Mas alla de eso, tambien esta respondido aca. Mas alla de eso (de vuelta) si tenes una duda mas puntual que no requiera escribir un capitulo de un libro, sos mas que bienvenido a volver a preguntar.

Comment: Una instancia es una referencia de una clase hacia otra con lo cual permite a ambas clases  ínteractuar entre si. Ejemplo: NombreDeClase [nombre_de_instancia] = new NombreDeClase();//con esto se hace una instancia